# Error positioning a Twitter Bootstrap alert box.

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, I want to display an alert using Twitter Bootstrap after a message is sent but the alert shows after the menu bar (as found in the image). I want the alert to show just like a JavaScript alert i.e. the contents of the page should be behind the alert. How do I do this? [image: enter image description ere]

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])){

                $param = array(
                'sender_id'=> $_SESSION['id'],
                'receiver_id' => $_POST['receiver_id'],
                'message'=> $_POST['message']

            );
                $sum = $param['receiver_id'] + $param['sender_id'];

                $sql1= "INSERT INTO message (sender_id, receiver_id, message, message_id) VALUES (:sender_id, :receiver_id, :message, '$sum')";
                $db->query($sql1, $param); 
                echo "


        <div class='alert alert-success'>

            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>

            <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.

        </div>
        ";                          
  }
```

Comment: Right now, if your query doesn't work as intended, will your program crash or will it display the success message? You need to look at request handling, specifically on success and fail, and how to use a modal to display a message when a page loads. While @sircrom has the right idea, his answer won't provide you with enough information to handle this question appropriately.

Comment: @TimLewis How do you feel I handle this when the query fails or succeeds?

Comment: Well, think about it, if the query fails, should the message say success? Usually, you'd use a `try{...} catch{...}` block around code that can fail, and act accordingly. Also, since a modal will be handled client-side while this request is server-side, you need to figure out when this message will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You can style this modals like u want it.

You can start the modal manually with this tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
```

**Edit:**
I dont know the way you handle your server side process, but this modal solution will just work well with ajax. I would suggest to do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Request
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myAjaxFolder/myServerSideProcess.php"
    })

    // Success
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#successModal').modal('show')
    })

    // Error
    .fail(function() {
        $('#errorModal').modal('show')
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't get it to show                                                                                                     <script>
  
   $('#basicModal').modal('show'); 
</script>                                                                                                          
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: You have to place it in $(document).ready(); i will update my answer.